# UWP and Json parsing

Tags: c#, json, async-await, uwp

I have method like this:

```
public static async void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var url = "http://10.0.0.68/SET Initialization";
        var url2 = "http://10.0.0.68/GET Status";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        Debug.WriteLine(response);
        response = await client.GetAsync(url2);
        Debug.WriteLine(response);
        var result =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonString = result.Substring(4);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MediaStatus));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        var data = (MediaStatus)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        Debug.Write(data.ProgNo);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message, exception.Source);
    }
}
```

MediaStatus.cs

```
[DataContract]
public class MediaStatus
{
    [DataMember(Name = "progNo")]
    public int ProgNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "index")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "group")]
    public int Group { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "msg")]
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "secondGroup")]
    public int SecondGroup { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "playFlag")]
    public int PlayFlag { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling it simply:

```
common.DoSomething();
```

**My problem is, that sometimes, the code is running well and will give me result, but sometimes I have an error:**

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
>   System.Private.DataContractSerialization:Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

I have to call two times `await client.GetAsync` with different urls

1. to say server that I would like to talk with him
2. to obtain status info

Comment: You're in an async method, why are you using .Result instead of await? Anyway, post the Json that it throws on. You might not be getting any Json returned which is making it throw.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, I changed it to:
     var result =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

but did not helped

Comment: It's likely malformed JSON. Can you post the JSON itself?

Comment: yes, you are right, the problem is not on my side, but on server side, sometimes returns wrong json string...

Comment: What is the `result.Substring(4);` for?  Is it to strip the byte order mark?  If so, why not just pass the return of `await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` to [`ReadObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908232.aspx) directly?  The internal reader should consume the BOM and set the encoding accordingly.

Comment: Because the result is: 

200 {"progNo":237,"index":7,"type":"tv","group":6,"msg":"","secondGroup":0,"playFlag":0}

Comment: Ehh I would say your problem is  var jsonString = result.Substring(4);  You shouldn't be substringing json. I have worked with a ton of JSON Apis including ones that I've built and I've never substringed anything

Comment: yes, but it begins with number 200 - which means success so I have to remove it..

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic issue where you're invoking a fire-and-forget, as your `DoSomething` method is defined as `async void`. The only entry point for [async](/questions/tagged/async) methods that should be marked as `void` are event handlers and the like. This method should instead be `Task` returning like this:

```
public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = "http://10.0.0.68/SET Initialization";
            var url2 = "http://10.0.0.68/GET Status";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            Debug.WriteLine(response);
            response = await client.GetAsync(url2);
            Debug.WriteLine(response);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonString = result.Substring(4);
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MediaStatus));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            var data = (MediaStatus)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            Debug.Write(data.ProgNo);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message, exception.Source);
    }
}
```

Additionally, the method should have the "Async" suffix to clearly indicate that the method is intended to be asynchronous. Likewise, I altered the use of the `HttpClient` such that it is wrapped in a `using` statement as it implements the `IDisposable` interface.

If you need to call this method from the an event handler, below is an example of doing so from the `.Loaded` event:

```
private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => 
    await common.DoSomethingAsync();
```